# How can I debug Apple push notifications not being received?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

I'm using [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails) to integrate Apple's Push Notifications with my service.

For a while, notifications seemed to be sent without issue. But now the notifications don't seem to be making it to people's iPhones/iPads.

According to our database, the notifications are being sent (`apn_on_rails` has a `sent_at` field that gets updated when the notification is sent). But no one (myself included) actually get the notifications.

Any ideas where to even start looking to debug this?

Comment: perhaps the notification certificate expired or something like that? (happens with development certficates)

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  Having a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are not displayed if the app is running. 
You can check the error response of the sending.